# How can I display availability per hour per day for each day of the week in my Python web app using HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Cannot display a breakdown of hours per day of the working week

What I want to achieve and fail, is to represent the availability of a person broken down per hours of day for each day of the working week: to do so, I have created the routes on my python web app and the template, where I tried to insert a loop under the `Availability` label, but nothing is shown in the web page, as below:

```
<h3>Availability:</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th> <!-- Empty header cell for spacing -->
                    {% for day in days_of_week %}
                    <th>{{ day }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for hour in hours %}
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ hour }}:00</th>
                    {% for day in days_of_week %}
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ 'availability_' + day.lower() + '_' + hour }}" name="{{ 'availability' + day.lower() + '_' + hour }}" value="true">
                    </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

(note that there is also code for Name and Subjects that are not in the snippet above and they work properly as input fields)

The python 3 code that should provide the variables is down below:

```
@app.route('/create_teacher', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def create_teacher():
        
        days_of_week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
        hours = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # Retrieve the form data
            name = request.form.get('name')
            subjects = request.form.get('subjects')
               
            # Access availability per hour per day from the form data
            availability = {}
            for day in days_of_week:
                availability[day] = {}
                for hour in hours:
                    availability[day][hour] = bool(request.form.get(f'availability_{day.lower()}_{hour}', False))
            

            # Insert the teacher document into the "teachers" collection
            result = coll.teachers.insert_one({
                                                'name': name,
                                                'subjects': subjects,
                                                'availability': availability
                                                })
    
            try:
                result.inserted_id
                print( "Teacher created successfully")
            except Exception as e:
                print( "Failed to create teacher, error is  " , e)
            
            return redirect(url_for('success'))
            return render_template('create_teacher.html', name=name, subjects=subjects, days_of_week=days_of_week, hours=hours)
        return render_template('create_teacher.html')
```

Unfortunately the result I obtain is a web page showing only the Availability header and nothing else. I need help to find where is my mistake, thanks.

Comment: `return redirect(url_for('success'))` prevents the `render_template` from ever running.

Comment: yes, it seems to work now thanks, I took `return redirect(url_for('success'))` out of the equation, thanks.